# on click, Stop a button from returning empty string and give an alert message using javascript

Tags: javascript

When I click on the "Add Note" button without entering any text, I do not want the localStorage to add an empty string. Instead, I want an `alert` message to pop up saying "enter a text".

I tried a few ways to place an `alert` at different points, but I get an error:

> ERROR: properties of null can't be read

Please suggest some code.

[image]

```js
 console.log("Add Notes");
 showNotes();
 
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let btnBag = document.getElementById("addBtn");
btnBag.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let txtBag = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notesBag == null) {
    notesBag = [];
  } else {
    notesBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
  }
  notesBag.push(txtBag.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesBag));
  txtBag.value = "";
  // showAlert();
  showNotes();
});
 
//Function to display elements located in localStorage
function showNotes(){
  // place the notes array in an element called notesBag
let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notesBag == null) {
    objBag = [];
  } else {
    objBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
  } 
  // create a blank string named html
  let html = '';
  // For the notesBag(which is parsed and placed into the objBag element) create forEach loop so that each notes stored in array is shown seperateley
  objBag.forEach(function (element,index) {
    html +=`
    <div id="notes" class=" row container-fluid">
            <div class="noteCard mx-2 my-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index+1}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
                    <button id = "${index} onclick = "deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> `;
  
    });
    let notesElem = document.getElementById("notes");
    
    if(objBag.length != 0){
      notesElem.innerHTML = html;
    } else { 
      notesElem.innerHTML = `Add Something for displaying the note`;
        }
    };
  

  //Delete a note





/* // Function to delete a note
function deleteNote(index) {


  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }

  notesObj.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  showNotes();
} */


// let search = document.getElementById('searchTxt');
// search.addEventListener("input", function(){

//     let inputVal = search.value.toLowerCase();
//     // console.log('Input event fired!', inputVal);
//     let noteCards = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
//     Array.from(noteCards).forEach(function(element){
//         let cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText;
//         if(cardTxt.includes(inputVal)){
//             element.style.display = "block";
//         }
//         else{
//             element.style.display = "none";
//         }
//         // console.log(cardTxt);
//     })
// })


/*Further Features:
1. Add Title
2. Mark a note as Important
3. Separate notes by user
4. Sync and host to web server 
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice code</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .navbar-brand {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Multiple Notes</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTxt" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success  my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container my-3">
        <h1>Take Notes Here</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add Note</h5>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn" onsubmit="showAlert()">Add Note</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h1>Your Notes</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="notes" class=" row container-fluid">
            <!-- <div class="noteCard mx-2 my-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">First Note</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="harry js files/practice.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your formatting is bad. Please fix the link. (edit queue is full)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a null check. please check the below code for your reference.

```
let btnBag = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    btnBag.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let txtBag = document.getElementById("addTxt");
      if(txtBag  && txtBag.value !="" && txtBag.value !=undefined ){
       let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
       if (notesBag == null) {
         notesBag = [];
       } else {
         notesBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
       }
       notesBag.push(txtBag.value);
       localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesBag));
       txtBag.value = "";
      // showAlert();
       showNotes();
     }
     else{
         alert('enter a text');
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay. In this code it was just enough to place the "txtBag" as not null or not undefined and place the alert immediately. Also you placed the alert at the end of the code. Let me know about why you have done it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a empty check and then throw an alert. (Marked with ****)

```js
console.log("Add Notes");
showNotes();

// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let btnBag = document.getElementById("addBtn");
btnBag.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let txtBag = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  if (txtBag.value == "") { //****
    alert("Empty Note");
    return
  }
  let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notesBag == null) {
    notesBag = [];
  } else {
    notesBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
  }
  notesBag.push(txtBag.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesBag));
  txtBag.value = "";
  // showAlert();
  showNotes();
});

//Function to display elements located in localStorage
function showNotes() {
  // place the notes array in an element called notesBag
  let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notesBag == null) {
    objBag = [];
  } else {
    objBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
  }
  // create a blank string named html
  let html = '';
  // For the notesBag(which is parsed and placed into the objBag element) create forEach loop so that each notes stored in array is shown seperateley
  objBag.forEach(function(element, index) {
    html += `
    <div id="notes" class=" row container-fluid">
            <div class="noteCard mx-2 my-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index+1}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
                    <button id = "${index} onclick = "deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> `;

  });
  let notesElem = document.getElementById("notes");

  if (objBag.length != 0) {
    notesElem.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    notesElem.innerHTML = `Add Something for displaying the note`;
  }
};


//Delete a note





/* // Function to delete a note
function deleteNote(index) {


  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }

  notesObj.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  showNotes();
} */


// let search = document.getElementById('searchTxt');
// search.addEventListener("input", function(){

//     let inputVal = search.value.toLowerCase();
//     // console.log('Input event fired!', inputVal);
//     let noteCards = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
//     Array.from(noteCards).forEach(function(element){
//         let cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText;
//         if(cardTxt.includes(inputVal)){
//             element.style.display = "block";
//         }
//         else{
//             element.style.display = "none";
//         }
//         // console.log(cardTxt);
//     })
// })


/*Further Features:
1. Add Title
2. Mark a note as Important
3. Separate notes by user
4. Sync and host to web server 
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice code</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .navbar-brand {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Multiple Notes</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTxt" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success  my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container my-3">
        <h1>Take Notes Here</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add Note</h5>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn" onsubmit="showAlert()">Add Note</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h1>Your Notes</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="notes" class=" row container-fluid">
            <!-- <div class="noteCard mx-2 my-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">First Note</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="harry js files/practice.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Supritam. I was actually playing with how to place a function for, when html is blank how we stop that from entering into local storage & give an alert.  Tried with placing .value and others inside functions. Always gave an error that null can't be read. Anyways Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check for undefined and empty string.

```
 let btnBag = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    btnBag.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        let txtBag = document.getElementById("addTxt");

        // Check for undefined and empty string, make sure user is
        // not able to send empty white spaces
        if(txtBag.value === undefined || txtBag.value.trim() === '') {
            alert('Please enter text to add note');
            return;
        }
        let notesBag = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notesBag == null) {
            notesBag = [];
        } else {
            notesBag = JSON.parse(notesBag);
        }
        notesBag.push(txtBag.value);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesBag));
        txtBag.value = "";
        // showAlert();
        showNotes();
    });
```

Comment: Thank You Prasad. I tried with .value and trim() and it said trim can't be used. It worked when I I ran it this way. Thanks